# Referencing to property from another property

Tags: flutter, dart

I've tried but couldn't find a way to reference one property from another, like this:

```
class Test {
  String prop1;
  String prop2;

  Test({this.prop1, this.prop2});
}

void main() {
  var test = Test(
    prop1: 'some text',
    // and here I want to reference to prop1 but this code is erroneous:
    prop2: '$prop1',
  );
```

Is there any way for it (like "this" in JS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot reference the `prop1` property before the `Test` object has been constructed. If you want `prop1` and `prop2` to be the same, create the `String` beforehand and use it for both of the arguments:

```dart
void main() {
  String prop = 'some text';
  var test = Test(
    prop1: prop,
    prop2: prop,
  );
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's the shame.Thanks for your help.